# How to get click event for a libVLC media playing on top of a CStaticCtrl

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, libvlc

I am playing a local media file on top a CStaticCtrl in a dialog based MFC application.I do get STN_DBCLICKED events normally as I would be getting.But when I embed the media using

```
libvlc media player set_hwnd(VLCInstance,m_Static.GetSafeHwnd());
```

I am unable to get any event.Even if I do

```
libvlc_video_set_mouse_input(pMedia,false);
```

The mouse pointer disappears when pointed to media(on moving to the static ctrl).
How can I get these events since I want to toggle fullscreen when user double clicks the window(Static Control window)?

What I have implemented till now is providing a button to the full screen and then I DoModal() a new dialog to play the video in full screen.I know this is not a clean way but I can't think of an alternative right now.Is there any other control that could work?

Comment: You can hook the windows messages to get valid events.

Comment: Thanks @santosh,But I am not sure what do you mean by "hook the windows messages".Could you please mention some details.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks